# PacketStream Explanation

Tags: proxy, packet

I have recently seen a website called PacketStream. I downloaded it and ran it for a bit. Then I wondered, how they bought their data from people. I always thought you needed port forwarding for proxies to work but how does PacketStream get a work-around for this?

Thanks in advance.